# Javascript para habilitar botão

Tags: javascript

Tenho um termo de uso, e preciso que o botão fique desabilitado até que o usuário clique no "li e concordo com os termos de uso. Podem me ajudar?

Comment: Com `Javascript` puro? Tem algum `HTML` de exemplo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É só você usar o evento `change` do `checkbox` para definir o valor da propriedade `disabled` do botão.

```js
const checkbox = document.querySelector('#chk');
const button = document.querySelector('#bt');

checkbox.addEventListener('change', (e) => button.disabled = !e.target.checked);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="chk" /> Li e concordo com os termos
<br>
<button id="bt" disabled>Prosseguir</button>
```

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo!